# Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system on Python and Azure Function

Tags: python, postgresql, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a Python function and deployed it on Azure Funtion. I used a TXT file to hold a time and I will use it.
On local, this function runs without problem. But I received the below error when run on Azure:

```
Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'date_time.txt' Stack:
```

In my search, I find some solutions like TempFile, but I need the value of date_time.txt for next time.

My code:

```
import os
import psycopg2
import datetime
import logging
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import json
import sqlalchemy
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
import azure.functions as func


connstr = "****"
topic_name = "***"
subscription_name = "***"


def get_engine(database='portal_rms', username='***', password='**', host='***', port=5432):
    engine_string = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_string)
    return engine


def read_from_db(table_name, date_time):
    acceleration_array = []
    engine = get_engine()
    connection = engine.connect()
    metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    pinconnector_attacheddevicelogdata = sqlalchemy.Table(
        table_name, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    query = sqlalchemy.select([pinconnector_attacheddevicelogdata]).where(pinconnector_attacheddevicelogdata.columns.capture_time > date_time)\
        .order_by(pinconnector_attacheddevicelogdata.columns.capture_time).limit(100)
    ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
    ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
    engine.dispose()
    return ResultSet


def get_date_time(date_time_string):
    [date, time] = date_time_string.split(" ")
    [year, month, day] = date.split("-")
    [hour, minute, second] = time.split(":")
    [second, microsecond] = second.split(".")
    [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond] = list(
        map(lambda x: int(x), [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond]))
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))


def write_date_time(date_time, address="date_time.txt"):
    file1 = open(address, "w+")
    file1.write((str(date_time)).split("+")[0])
    file1.close()


def read_date_time(address="date_time.txt"):
    file1 = open(address, "r")
    date_time = file1.readline()
    date_time = get_date_time(date_time)
    file1.close()
    return date_time


def get_query_latest_date_time(db_query, date_time):
    for item in db_query:
        if item["capture_time"] > date_time:
            date_time = item["capture_time"]
    return date_time


def transform(query_row):
    query_row = dict(query_row)
    for item in ['capture_time', 'received_time', 'read_time']:
        query_row[item] = str(query_row[item]).split("+")[0]
    return query_row


date_time = read_date_time()
db_query = read_from_db("pinconnector_attacheddevicelogdata", date_time)
write_date_time(db_query[-1]["capture_time"])
# print(db_query)
#data_send = json.dumps(db_query)
data_send = json.dumps(list(map(lambda x: transform(x), db_query)))


with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connstr) as client:
    with client.get_topic_sender(topic_name) as sender:
        sender.send_messages(ServiceBusMessage(data_send))
```

Comment: Don't attempt to use the filesystem in an Azure Function. There's no guarantee that the same server will be used to execute your function on two successive runs, so even if you could write to the filesystem you might find that on subsequent runs the file appears not to be there.  If you need to store state between runs of the function, store it elsewhere, e.g. in Azure Storage.

Answer (score -1):

The reason could be an incompatible OS version. Please consider [custom container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp) in this case.

You may also refer to this similar issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67126/failure-exception-oserror-errno-30-read-only-file.html