# Azure function python Read-only file system: 'chromedriver.zip'

Tags: python, azure-functions

> Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'chromedriver.zip' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 402, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 611, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger1/**init**.py", line 41, in main driver = uc.Chrome(options=options) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/**init**.py", line 47, in **new** ChromeDriverManager(*args, **kwargs).install() File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/**init**.py", line 195, in install self.fetch_chromedriver() File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/**init**.py", line 227, in fetch_chromedriver urlretrieve( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 249, in urlretrieve tfp = open(filename, 'wb')

I am trying to run an undetected chrome driver on Azure function and getting this error. Locally everything works fine. How to solve it?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error occurs when you are trying to write something in the function. Azure function are a read only system. The error can be caused by the incompatibility of the **os**.
The following thread has a similar issue:
[postgresql - Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system on Python and Azure Function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297603/result-failure-exception-oserror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-on-python-a)

also this one

[“Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system” when using AzureML in Python Azure Function - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67126/failure-exception-oserror-errno-30-read-only-file.html).

Also refer the following [article](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-headless-chromium-puppeteer-playwright/) on using chrome in azure function .